# Is it possible to work with front react with axios and back java dynamic web with jersey?

Tags: reactjs, jersey, eclipse-jee

I’m developing a web application using react and java JEE. Is it possible to connect via react refux, axios with backend. I’m using java dynamic web with jersey for my backend.

Can you suggest any technology?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. You have to choose the technology based on your requirements.